# Converting a DNS packet to a string using Scapy

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I want to convert a DNS packet to a string like DNS(packet).show() does. However, all that the show method does is print out the information. I want to store that exact same information in a string. Is there any specific way to do this?

Comment: I've had a look at the methods of the class. There doesn't seem to be any method that does what the show() method does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet will help:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> import sys
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> old_stdout = sys.stdout
>>> sys.stdout = mystdout = StringIO()
>>> pkt = DNS()
>>> pkt.show()
>>> sys.stdout = old_stdout
>>> mystdout.getvalue()
'###[ DNS ]###\n  id        = 0\n  qr        = 0\n  opcode    = QUERY\n  aa        = 0\n  tc        = 0\n  rd        = 0\n  ra        = 0\n  z         = 0\n  rcode     = ok\n  qdcount   = 0\n  ancount   = 0\n  nscount   = 0\n  arcount   = 0\n  qd        = None\n  an        = None\n  ns        = None\n  ar        = None\n'
>>>
```

Comment: LOL! I didn't expect this one to get downvoted. Well, whoever downvoted it, please do share a better way to retrieve pkt.show() as a string. I currently use this method at work and if there is a better way I will be sure to use that instead.

Comment: This is actually pretty much exactly what I was looking for. I'm sure it's not the most orthodox way of doing it, but it works. I have no idea why someone would downvote this.